# How to preserve selected status for UITableViewCell when scrolling off and back on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell cells in a UITableView.  When a cell is selected by the user and the cell is scrolled off the screen, and then scrolled back into the screen, the selected cell is blank.

I know that I need to set all values in the cell as the cells are reused, but I have not been able to figure this one out.

Iamge 1 represents a user selecting the cell:

[image: Table when a cell is selected]

Image 2 represents when the cell is scrolled off screen and back on screen
[image: Table when the cell is scrolled off screen and back on screen]

(Ignore the fact the images are blurred, simply protecting my customers data)

*Note:  I want to be able to select the table, don't suggest to remove the ability to highlight the cell.  I actually want to be able to see the blue cell when scrolling a selected cell back into the screen.*

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:  Adding some code:

```
// Define a property to keep track of the cell that was selected last using the NSIndexPath
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *lastSelectedIndexPath;

///////

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Keeps track of the lastest selected entry
    self.lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    IPCSearchResultTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Cast the cell to the custom cell
    IPCSearchResultTableViewCell *searchResultCell = (IPCSearchResultTableViewCell *)cell;

    // RepositoryIndex is a coredata object with information 
    MyCoreDataEntity *entity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    searchResultCell.label1.text = entity.attribute1;
    searchResultCell.label2.text = entity.attribute2;
    searchResultCell.label3.text = entity.attribute3;
    searchResultCell.label4.text = entity.attribute4;
}
```

***NOTE:   The code above now seems to be working. I am not experiencing this issue anymore and don't know why ***

Comment: Could you post some code? It probably has to do with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: and didSelectRowAtIndexPath  also

Answer (score 0):

have you tried maintaining an array of index paths (of selected cells)

then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method set the [cell setSelected:] method if the indexPath is in the array.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I do.